# $f$ convex; $\int_{\Omega} f(u_n(x)) dx \leq C$. Any compactness result?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a convex function ($f(0)$ can be $\infty$, e.g. $f(s)= \frac{1}{s^2} +s$, $s>0$).

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $(u_n)$ be a set of non-negative functions satisfying $f(u_n) \in L^1(\Omega)$.

We further assume there exists C>0 s.t.
$$
\int_{\Omega} f(u_n(x)) dx \leq C.
$$

My question: Can we expect any compactness result of $(u_n)$? (e.g. weak $L^p$ compactness).

Perhaps, my statement allows a counterexample, but you can assume a strong assumption for $u_n$ to obtain some compactness result. Please notice that the intention of this question is to investigate any compactness result in the situation above.

Comment: Dundford Pettis Theorem characterises weak compactnes in $L^{1}$ in terms of the inequalities of this type.

Comment: I think what you need (irrespective of the convexity) is that $f(x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then you will get weak compactness by the Dunford Pettis theorem mentioned by @geetha290krm

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much. I found a breakthrough due to your advice.

Comment: @PhoemueX Do you mean sublinearity of $f$? According to my research, we need super linearity of $f$ to apply DunfordPettis Theorem.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $f(x) / x \to \infty$.